Why did the binding not take effect
I created the derived class MyTextBox of the TextBox class and added a dependency property named AString and a routing event named ContextChangedEvent. In the XAML code, the Text property was bound to the AString property, but when I changed the value of the Text property, the setter of the AString property was not triggered, which means the binding did not take effect. Why is this?
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ContentChangedEvent;
    public event RoutedEventHandler ContentChanged
    {
        add { AddHandler(ContentChangedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ContentChangedEvent, value); }
    }

    public string AString
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(AStringProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(AStringProperty, value);
            OnContentChanged();
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AStringProperty;

    static MyTextBox()
    {
        ContentChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ContentChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyTextBox));
        var a = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("555");
        a.BindsTwoWayByDefault = true;
        AStringProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AString", typeof(string), typeof(MyTextBox), a);
    }
    private void OnContentChanged()
    {
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ContentChangedEvent, this));
    }

 <local:MyTextBox x:Name="mtb1"
                  ContentChanged="MyTextBox_ContentChanged"
                  Text="{Binding AString,
                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self},
                                 Mode=TwoWay}" />

I tried changing the binding mode to bidirectional binding, but it didn't work

"the setter of the AString property was not triggered, which means the binding did not take effect." - it means that framework doesn't call setter and uses SetValue directly. use DependencyProperty.Register overload which has property change callback

The CLR property is just a proxy wrapper for the Dependency Property. There should be no logic in this wrapper other than getting and setting the property value.
Here is the correct implementation:
    public class MyTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public event RoutedEventHandler ContentChanged
        {
            add => AddHandler(ContentChangedEvent, value);
            remove => RemoveHandler(ContentChangedEvent, value);
        }
        public static readonly RoutedEvent ContentChangedEvent
            = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
                nameof(ContentChanged),
                RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
                typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
                typeof(MyTextBox));

        public string AString
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(AStringProperty);
            set => SetValue(AStringProperty, value);// OnContentChanged();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AStringProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                nameof(AString),
                typeof(string),
                typeof(MyTextBox),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("555")
                {
                    BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
                    PropertyChangedCallback = OnContentChanged
                });
        private static void OnContentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           ((UIElement)d).RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ContentChangedEvent, d));
        }
    }

P.S. And please explain why you need the second string property in the TextBox?
